How would a first-class lever with an effort arm of 0 become balanced?
I know this is probably a very simple question, but I was learning about the law of the lever in class and became curious. The law of the lever states that for a lever to be balanced, the effort arm multiplied by the effort force is equal to the product of the resistance arm and the resistance force. However, if the effort arm is 0 (assuming a first class lever in which the fulcrum is in the center, is it possible to balance the lever? Or, if not, could it be balanced by use of a second or third-class lever?

THis is actually a really good question for a "try it and see" sort of experiment.  Try lifting a load with your effort arm getting shorter and shorter, and see what happens.  See if you can infer what would happen if the effort arm was 0.  Then try a lever from the other classes and see if the result changes.


The law of the lever states that for a lever to be balanced, the effort arm multiplied by the effort force is equal to the product of the resistance arm and the resistance force.

OK, I heard you say,
$$a_ef_e=a_rf_r$$
Where $a$ stands for "arm," $f$ for "force", $e$ for "effort," and $r$ for "resistance."

if the effort arm is 0...

$$0f_e=a_rf_r$$
Or, more simply,
$$0 = a_rf_r$$
Seems like there's two ways you can make that equation true.
